# Why invitees/details of Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.Appointment are empty

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, appointment

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 application, and this app want to get the meetings from Calendar.
I am using the Windows Runtime api to get all appointment like this:

```
AppointmentStore appointmentStore = await AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType.AllCalendarsReadOnly);

IReadOnlyList<Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.Appointment> appointments = await appointmentStore.FindAppointmentsAsync(DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromHours(24)); ;
        foreach (var appointment in appointments)
        {
            var persistentId = appointment.RoamingId;
            var details = appointment.Details;//the details is empty, why
            var invitees = appointment.Invitees;//the invitees is also empty, why?
        }
```

Actually, I tried the Microsoft Phone api, I can get the details and attendees(invitees). However, the Microsoft Phone api can't get the appointment ID. Can anybody throw me some light how to get both appointment ID, and details/invitees? Thanks!

```
Appointments appts = new Appointments();

            //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
            appts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<AppointmentsSearchEventArgs>(Calendar_SearchCompleted);

            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime end = start.AddDays(1);
            int max = 100;
            appts.SearchAsync(start, end, max, "test");

private async void Calendar_SearchCompleted(object sender, AppointmentsSearchEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Appointment appt in e.Results)
        {
            var details = appt.Details;//I can get the details

            var participants = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
            var attendees = appt.Attendees;
            if (attendees != null)
            {
                foreach (var attende in attendees)
                {
                    Person attendPerson = new Person()
                    {
                        Email = attende.EmailAddress,
                        FullName = attende.DisplayName,
                        PersonID = attende.EmailAddress
                    };

                    participants.Add(attendPerson);
                }

            }



            ....
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your need to add FindAppointmentsOptions to get get whatever detail you want, try below code

```
 AppointmentStore appointmentStore = await AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType.AllCalendarsReadOnly);

        FindAppointmentsOptions options = new FindAppointmentsOptions();
        options.MaxCount = 100;
        options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.Subject);
        options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.Location);
        options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.Invitees);
        options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.Details);
        options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.StartTime);
        options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.ReplyTime);
        IReadOnlyList<Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.Appointment> appointments = await appointmentStore.FindAppointmentsAsync(DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromHours(24), options);
        foreach (var appointment in appointments)
        {
            var persistentId = appointment.RoamingId;
            var details = appointment.Details;//the details is empty, why
            var invitees = appointment.Invitees;//the invitees is also empty, why?
        }
```